# Jenkins Multibranch Pipeline triggering builds from multiple SCM repos

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkinsfile pipeline configured and a multibranch pipeline pointed to a git repository, (A).  In the same Jenkinsfile I pull down code from git repository, (B) to perform some independent steps.

I would like to have jenkins poll the A repo - and whenever it finds a change - build it.  This is working.

However, it is also polling repo B. Whenever a change occurs in repo B (which is often) it picks up the change and starts a build.

How can I turn off polling from for this other repo?  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is a known issue. https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-38508

Comment: In my case I found that I could get around the issue by properly cleaning out my workspace at the end of the build process.  Since there was nothing to compare to, the secondary repo, B, could detect no change.
Used step([$class: 'WsCleanup']) to clean up.

Answer (score 1):

Using the pipeline syntax snippet generator in Jenkins I come up with this:

```
checkout poll: false, scm: [$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/master']], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[]]]
```

Comment: For checking out repo A, I'm using `checkout scm`.  For checking out repo B, i'm using `git branch: 'production', credentialsId: '00000000-0000-0000-0000-00000000', url: 'git@host:repo.git'`
I don't suppose I could use the poll option with 'git branch'.  Perhaps I'm doing it wrong by pulling repo B with the git command?

Comment: I switched from the git branch command to checkout scm like you suggested (including poll: false,) but it's still triggering commits when the second repo (B) has a commit.

Comment: Could it be a solution that you try to find out from inside the Pipeline script which repository triggered the build, and then just abort the build in case it was the wrong one?